# This property cannot be set to a null value error .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a website on .NET 4.0 MVC4 with a **MySQL database**, and I was getting this "Property cannot be set to a null value" error.

Description:

I have several tables in a MySQL database, and most of them contain nullable properties (most of them strings). Then, in my .NET project, I have my .edmx file, which I created using the wizard, so that file was made automatically, from the database I already had.

But while I was testing, I got this error I already mentioned. So I did a little reaserch and i found out that the problem was this:

```
_propertyName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
```

That line, it verifies that the value of the property is not null, even though the 'Nullable' checkbox was checked on the database client (HeidiSQL in my case). The temporary solution that i found is that if I change 'false' for 'true' in that line, it works. It looks like this:

```
_propertyName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
```

The problem is that I have lots of nullable properties in different tables, I need to find a way to make the EntityFramework understand that i want those properties to allow null as a value, without having to search for every field in my Designer and change it manually.

Comment: have you declare your property with a Nullable type? e.g. an integer nullable variable declared as int? i; just put a 'Question Mark' after the data type of your property.

Comment: Everything that it has to do with the declaration of the properties in  the designer it was made by the Entity Data Model Wizard. What I want to avoid here is having to go one by one modifying the type. What you say can be done, i just want to find a more elegant solution. Plus, probably next time i refresh my .edmx, i'll lose all the modifications.

Comment: There must be a reason for the edmx generator to see the properties as not nullable (for nullable properties it will generate code with `true`). Try to dig into that reason. Maybe an issue of the MySql data provider?